# How to implement a map with unique keys that are themselves tables in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Most languages offer some way to implements maps efficiently for ANY type of key either using an equivalence relation and a hashing function (with hash tables) or using an order relation (with trees).

However it seems Lua tables only offer this for strings. Specifically, if using a Lua table (implementing an "object" conceptually) as a key, it could only be looked up again with a reference to the same object, but not a new object with the same "contents".

This is kind of required to implement behavior similar to a database index or a cache for some value based on "unique" keys, at least without resorting to linear time lookup.

The only thing I could think of, is if the key object is made from fields `f1,...,fn`, we could make a bunch of nested maps and look it up like this `T[f1][f2]...[fn]` (at least if the fields are themselves integers or strings). This is kinda awful and breaks the intent of encapsulating `f1,...,fn` into an "object".

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you triedv overriding the `__index` metamethod on your table? It allows you to handle the way indexes are used yourself. You could then check for the key table's contents instead of its reference. See http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you want may be something like [this](http://siffiejoe.github.io/lua-multikey/).

Otherwise a valid approach would be to serialize your key to a string in a deterministic way and use the result (or a hash of it) as the key.

Like SolarBear told you in a comment, you can then use methamethods to make it have the same interface as a regular table.

Comment: wouldn't using a hash of the key rely on there being no hash collisions at all? even overriding __index wouldn't prevent it from overwriting an earlier entry with the same hash value [if I understood it properly]

Comment: @catwell For clarification - I suppose that when you say *serialize in a deterministic way* you mean creating a one-to-one mapping between the actual key and its internal string representation.

Comment: @yonil if you use a hash you will have to handle collisions yourself inside __index and __newindex. I suppose that hashing could be beneficial only if the internal string representation becomes too big and wastes lots of memory. A suitable hash function could be a way to "compress" it. I suppose it is a tradeoff memory vs. implementation complexity (@catwell if I guessed correctly what you had in mind).

Comment: Yes, it is a tradeoff, but if you want to use large tables as keys it is a really good one. As for collisions, you could just use a hashing function with technically no risk of collision like SHA-256. And for serialization you could use probably the internal representation, or just any "fast enough" serialization library that has the properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can index tables with tables, thus allowing to use them as reference.

```
local cache = {}
local t = {}
cache[t] = 345 -- key is not important, but must not equal nil
local other = {
  ref = t
}

...
print(cache[other.ref]
```